# Programmatically adding a Site to Internet Explorer’s Trusted Sites Zone?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, vbscript

The script below adds my site to the trusted sites zone for my users so that are able to run an activeX control.

It works perfect on my localhost and the URL is added to the trusted sites zone. But it doesn't do anything and the last message does appear when copying the webpage containing the script to the online production website. What am I doing wrong here?

Can someone help me or suggest another way to achieve the same task?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/vbscript">


On Error Resume Next

Sub addkey

Dim DomainArray,  strComputer, strHTTP, strHTTPS

Dim dwordZone, regPath, objReg, counter, subkeyPath, icounter

Dim subkeyValue

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001


DomainArray = "mydomain.ca"

strComputer = "."
strHTTP = "http"
strHTTPS = "https"
dwordZone = "2"

regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" &_
"\ZoneMap\Domains\"
'Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
subkeyPath = regPath & DomainArray
objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,subkeyPath
regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" &_
"\ZoneMap\Domains\mydomain.ca\" 
subkeyPath = regPath & "www"
objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,subkeyPath
objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,subkeyPath,strHTTPS,dwordZone
MsgBox("https://www.mydomain.ca has been added to the Trusted Sites Zone.") 
objReg.DeleteValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkeyPath, strHTTPEnd Sub

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything like that from a normal web page. It would be an enormous security disaster if random web pages could diddle with your Registry. The whole point of the Trusted Sites Zone is that the user has to explicitly state they trust the site enough to put it there.

So the only reasonable approach to getting a site in the Trusted Sites Zone is to ask the user to manually add it. However, this is still generally inappropriate and unnecessary just to run an ActiveX control. What are you actually trying to do with this ActiveX control?

Comment: We have a recording/playback software that was developed long time ago and we run it as an activeX on our English learning website. So to spare the users being prompted by the browser every time they try to use the software, we ask them to add the website to Trusted sites zone and change the setting for this zone  to allow download and run of ActiveX.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be in the Trusted Sites Zone just to download or run an ActiveX control. Outside of the Trusted Sites Zone you'll get the yellow infobar on the first download, but click through that and it should be possible to install the control, as long as it is correctly code-signed. After that it should generally run without further prompting, as long as it is marked safe to include on a web page.